# Why are globals empty inside a class when the variabled are included?

Tags: php, class, global

What I am trying to do is have a separate PHP file containing settings for the website, and then having other pages include this file and execute code according to the settings. However, whenever I use global to reference these variables inside a class, the variables are empty. For example:

settings.php:

```
<?php
$setting1 = 'on';
$setting2 = 'off';
?>
```

class.php:

```
<?php
require_once('./settings.php');

class myclass {
  public function __construct {
    global $setting1;
    echo $setting1;
  }
}

$object = new myclass;
?>
```

This prints nothing. However, if I do "echo $setting1" outside of the class, it prints 'on'. When I tried setting the variable inside the file itself rather than including it, in printed 'on' when I created a new object for myclass. Is there something special I need to do to make the included variables available in the global scope for the class?

Comment: You may want to consider creating a static class instead of global vars for reasons of namespace safety.  To directly answer your question, it does seem like the parentheses issues the others have mentioned.

Answer (score 8):

Your constructor needs brackets after its name, e.g.

```
public function __construct() {

}
```

I suspect this is giving you a fatal error and that is not being shown because of your [display_errors](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) / [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) settings.

Comment: Thanks. I added this, however I'm still facing the same problem: included variables aren't available in the global scope for the class.

Answer (score 1):

You were missing the parentheses:

```
public function __construct {
```

should be

```
public function __construct( ) {
```

Result:

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.2.5 (cli) (built: Nov 29 2007 09:31:38) 
2007-Macbook:Desktop mark$ php class.php
on
```